# What does the small print below "ESTA" and "non-US citizens" on the LAX immigration signs say?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, airports, los-angeles, lax

[image: 1]

In this image, there's small print below "ESTA" (left green sign), "Non-US citizens" (right green sign) and "Non-US citizens" (Grey sign).

Does any one know what it actually says?

Also, what is Express Connection (orange sign)?

Comment: **Express Connections** is if you are in a hurry to catch a connecting flight because your inbound flight was running late. You will (or should) be given an orange card as you alight the aircraft allowing you to push to the front of the immigration and customs queue.

Comment: @Calchas Interesting, does that line lead to an APC kiosk? Because if you, for example, expected to use APC and therefore didn't fill out a customs form, but then need to go through Express Connections, you might have to fill out the form in the immigration hall - not very convenient

Comment: The green line at LAX is also available to B1/B2 visa holders, and Lawful Permanent Residents. That may be the text underneath.

Comment: No, it would probably be quicker to use APC or Global Entry than express connections.

Comment: @Calchas B1/B2 makes sense (it says so in the article), but LPR:s are on the left green sign. However, I'm particularly curious about the text underneath "ESTA" as some Airports allow first-time ESTAs to use the kiosks. Do first-time ESTAs follow the left green, right green, or Grey sign?

Comment: @Crazydre regarding expectations of APC: I recently returned to Newark and failed to fill out the landing card as I was expecting to use APC (thanks to the information on the CBP website).  But the CBP website did not note that APC is available only in one terminal; I was arriving in another terminal.  I filled out the card in the hall, ending up nearly last in the line despite being one of the first off the plane, and had to worry about whether I'd catch grief from the officer for filling out a Spanish-language form despite the fact that I don't speak Spanish.  It took me 2 hours to get out.

Comment: @phoog TBIT (where this picture is taken) has had APC machines for nearly two years IIRC

Comment: @Calchas I don't understand why you're telling me that.  Is it in reaction to something I said?

Comment: @phoog I thought you were suggesting that APC might not actually be available on Crazydre's journey.

Comment: @Calchas no, I was just reacting to the example of a traveler who was planning to use APC but ended up going to Express Connections and therefore had to fill out a customs form in the hall.  My experience supports the conclusion that this is "not very convenient."

Comment: You could always [ask them for a larger picture](https://twitter.com/flylaxairport/status/764578613299646464).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did remember to take some pictures, but the flash was turned off and lighting was not great. So. Here is the left side of the sign.

[image: Left side of the immigration signs at LAX]

In the middle is Global Entry.

All three on the categories on the left say "AUTOMATED PASSPORT CONTROL" at the bottom and have a person-at-a-kiosk symbol at left. From the left,

```
 1. U.S. Citizens & Canadian Citizens 
 2. ESTA
    VISA WAIVER COUNTRIES
    Lawful Permanent Residents
 3. Non - U.S. Citizens
    TRAVELING ON A B1-B2 VISA OR A BORDER CROSSING CARD
 4. GLOBAL ENTRY
    TRUSTED TRAVELER NETWORK
```

Here is the photo of the right side.

[image: Right side of immigration signs at LAX]

```
 5. Express Connection
 6. Non - U.S. Citizens
    TRAVELING ON A VISA
 7. Crew, APEC 
    Diplomats
    Special Assistance
```

Side note: I never had to turn in my customs card.  The final guy, who I would have expected to take it, just wanted my kiosk receipt. The receipt has your photo that was taken then, no hats nor glasses.

Courtesy Comment from [@Calchas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78403/what-does-the-small-print-below-esta-and-non-us-citizens-on-the-lax-immigrat#comment174961_78403):

> **Express Connections** is if you are in a hurry to catch a connecting flight because your inbound flight was running late. You will (or should) be given an orange card as you alight the aircraft allowing you to push to the front of the Immigration and Customs queue.

Comment: I should have asked about express connection. They have different lanes for customs. The ANZ  crew were giving cards to people who were transiting, so I think it's for them.

Comment: I'm in a sedan on the way home; not happening right now!

Comment: Of course. The blue forms are only needed for those who don't qualify for APC. The APC receipt replaces it. Anyway, **thanks heaps**, I'll be sure to watch the pics once you're home

Comment: @Crazydre that makes sense about the cards. I'd said yes to bring food in (sweets and chips, yes, I know, I'm a stickler) but the kiosk question was more precise and I answered no on a similar question.

Comment: @mkennedy As my biometrics are already in CBP's system (which is why I qualify for APC), I always refuse to take the blue form, even when ignorant crew says "**all** foreign citizens have to". Of course it would be a different story if I went to an Airport without APC, or an Airport like PHL where only US citizens/perm. residents qualify for APC, but I haven't been to such an Airport so far since APC was introduced

Comment: @mkennedy A question: would it be OK if I uploaded the left pic on Flyertalk's "US CBP Automated Passport Control" post? Or maybe you could do it? This would be useful for Readers to know

Comment: @Crazydre I hereby state they're under Creative Commons Share-Alike. Go right ahead!